# Facebook auth in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, fbsdk

Can I add several projects to one facebook account?

For example, I have project **`A`** in `developers.facebook.com`. And I want to add project **`B`** to project **`A`** for making common user database. Is it possible?

Is it possible to add several `Bundle ID` and `App ID in store` to one project in `developers.facebook.com`?

I want to use login with facebook feature.

Comment: You can create different projects (with different bundle ids, of course) under the same Facebook account.

Comment: @Hamed, yeap, I know about that, but actually that is not what I want. Anyway, thanks for your response

Comment: If you want to be able to match users across different apps, then you need to first of all add those apps to the same business; afterwards you can match up the app-scoped user ids you got. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_243683436008228